# SSH through a gateway that needs a proxy to access final destination

Tags: ssh, http-proxy, gateway

I have to set up an ssh/sftp connection which needs a certain configuration, and I've been looking around but didn't find an answer. I'm not sure it's even possible without some work around.

I have 4 IPs (like the below example):

1. 192.168.0.10 - User PC
2. 172.16.0.10 - SSH gateway
3. 10.0.0.10 - Proxy server
4. 30.30.30.30 - SSH server on the internet

What I need is to SSH from 1 to 4, using the ssh gateway, which requires the proxy (3) to access the internet.
Currently i'm able to connect from 1 to 4 if i set up the proxy on 1 without passing by 2, but this is not acceptable.
And I'm able to connect from 2 to 4 using the proxy.
But if I try to connect from 1 to 4, using the gateway, I'm not sure how to tell the gateway to use the proxy.
The tools I can use are netcat and connect-proxy on machine 1 and 2, but ProxyJump is not installed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is looking for an answer to the same question, i found a way to make this work:
*~/.ssh/config*

Host gateway
Hostname 172.16.0.10
User gatewayuser

Host sshserver
Hostname 30.30.30.30
User sshuser
ProxyCommand ssh gateway connect-proxy -H 10.0.0.10:8080 %h %p

Then from the client machine 192.168.0.10:
$ ssh sshserver